# Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am setting up a unit test for MS Bot dialog and am getting the following error and not sure how to resolve it.  Can anyone help?  Thanks

> *Error CS4010  Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type '`Task<HttpOperationResponse<BotData>>`'. An async lambda expression may return void, Task or `Task<T>`, none of which are convertible to '`Task<HttpOperationResponse<BotData>>`'. 
>   D3DirectlineBot.UnitTests   C:\Repos\D3DirectlineBot\D3DirectlineBot.UnitTests\MockConnectorFactory.cs  109 Active*

**Mock Class**

```
public Mock<StateClient> MockIBots(MockConnectorFactory mockConnectorFactory)
{
    var botsClient = new Moq.Mock<StateClient>(MockBehavior.Loose);

    botsClient.Setup(d => d.BotState.SetConversationDataWithHttpMessagesAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<BotData>(), It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .Returns<string, string, BotData, Dictionary<string, List<string>>, CancellationToken>(async (channelId, conversationId, data, headers, token) =>
        {
            return await mockConnectorFactory.UpsertData(channelId, null, conversationId, BotStoreType.BotConversationData, data);
        });

        return botsClient;
    }
```

**UpsertData Class**

```
protected async Task<HttpOperationResponse<object>> UpsertData(string channelId, string userId, string conversationId, BotStoreType storeType, BotData data)
{
    var _result = new HttpOperationResponse<object>();
    _result.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    try
    {
        var address = AddressFrom(channelId, userId, conversationId);
        await memoryDataStore.SaveAsync(address, storeType, data, CancellationToken.None);
    }
    catch (HttpException e)
    {
        _result.Body = e.Data;
        _result.Response = new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed };
        return _result;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        _result.Response = new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError };
        return _result;
    }
    _result.Body = data;
    _result.Response = new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
    return _result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UpsertData Class**: Change `HttpOperationResponse<object>` to `HttpOperationResponse<Botdata>`

```
protected async Task<HttpOperationResponse<Botdata>> UpsertData(string channelId, string userId, string conversationId, BotStoreType storeType, BotData data)
{
    var _result = new HttpOperationResponse<Botdata>();
    _result.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    try
    {
        var address = AddressFrom(channelId, userId, conversationId);
        await memoryDataStore.SaveAsync(address, storeType, data, CancellationToken.None);
    }
    catch (HttpException e)
    {
        _result.Body = data;
        _result.Response = new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed };
        return _result;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        _result.Response = new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError };
        return _result;
    }
    _result.Body = data;
    _result.Response = new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
    return _result;
}
```

**MockConnectionFactory Class**: Removed `async` and `await` as mentioned by @DmitryBogatykh

```
    botsClient.Setup(d => d.BotState.SetConversationDataWithHttpMessagesAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<BotData>(), It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .Returns((string channelId, string conversationId, BotData data, Dictionary<string, List<string>> headers, CancellationToken token) =>
        {
            return  mockConnectorFactory.UpsertData(channelId, null, conversationId, BotStoreType.BotConversationData, data);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just return Task without awaiting for it:

```
return mockConnectorFactory.UpsertData(channelId, null, conversationId, BotStoreType.BotConversationData, data);
```

Comment: Now this Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationResponse<object>>' to 'Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationResponse<Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotData>' D3DirectlineBot.UnitTests C:\Repos\D3DirectlineBot\D3DirectlineBot.UnitTests\MockConnectorFactory.cs 104 Active

Comment: And this error Error CS4010 Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type 'Task<HttpOperationResponse<BotData>>'. An async lambda expression may return void, Task or Task<T>, none of which are convertible to 'Task<HttpOperationResponse<BotData>>'. D3DirectlineBot.UnitTests C:\Repos\D3DirectlineBot\D3DirectlineBot.UnitTests\MockConnectorFactory.cs 135 Active

Comment: You should remove the async keyword here: CancellationToken>(async (channelId

Comment: removed the async.  But does not two solve errors mentioned above